# How to restrict access to a route in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route which don't want user to access it directly even if user has login. I only want my route to be accessible from my handler in the code. Is there a way to achieve it?

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/protected' component={Protected}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some solution.
Idea is to pre process routes based on user permissions before this routes will be put into the router:

```
    const routes = [
      {
          path: "/example",
          component: Example,
          permissions: ['examplePermission']
      },
      {
          path: "/example2",
          component: Example2,
          permissions: ['examplePermission2']
      }
    ];
    
    const processYourRoutes = (routes, userPermissions) => {
    return routes
      .filter(route => 
          route.permissions.some(routePermission => 
          userPermissions.includes(routePermission)))
      .map(route => <Route path={route.path} component={route.component}/>);
    };
    
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            { processYourRoutes() }
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

How to organize user permissions is up to you. There are a lot of ways.

Example how it works:

```js
 const routes = [
      {
          path: "/example",
          // component: Example,
          component: 'Example', // Impoted component instead like above
          permissions: ['examplePermission']
      },
      {
          path: "/example2",
          // component: Example2,
          component: "Example2", // Impoted component instead like above
          permissions: ['examplePermission2']
      }
    ];

    const userPermissions = ['examplePermission', 'examplePermission2'];
    
    const processYourRoutes = (routes, userPermissions) => {
    return routes
      .filter(route => 
          route.permissions.some(routePermission => 
          userPermissions.includes(routePermission)))
      // .map(route => <Route path={route.path} component={route.component}/>);
      .map(route => 'route.path: ' + route.path + ' = ' + 'route.component: ' + route.component); // Route like above instead
    };

    console.log(processYourRoutes(routes, userPermissions));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by handler, but I believe you could create a private route like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, handler, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !handler ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Component {...props} />
      }
    />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

and then in your app.js you would use your PrivateRoute like so:

first make sure to import the PrivateRoute file

```
import PrivateRoute from 'path to private route'
```

and then inside your switch:

```
 

<Router>
  <Switch>
   <PrivateRoute
     path="/protected"
     component={Protected}
     handler={handler}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ProtectedRoute component which has all the logic to verifiy if you're allowed to access or not to the route, in case you have not the access, then redirect to another place.

Related question with an example i made: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64628792/redirect-to-login-page-when-token-is-invalid-on-react/64629004#64629004)