# Is this component being rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to do the same thing as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64628792/redirect-to-login-page-when-token-is-invalid-on-react), then created a component named [`ProtectedRoute`](https://github.com/shiv-chan/senpai-kohai/blob/feature-profile-setting/client/src/common/components/ProtectedRoute.tsx).

Placed `ProtectedRoute` in [`App.tsx`](https://github.com/shiv-chan/senpai-kohai/blob/feature-profile-setting/client/src/App.tsx). This is supposed to render multiple `ProtectedRoute` components maping over [`ProtectedRoutes`](https://github.com/shiv-chan/senpai-kohai/blob/feature-profile-setting/client/src/config/protectedRoutes.ts).

When the `ProtectedRoute` component gets rendered it sends an HTTP request to verify the token.

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/authorization', {
                withCredentials: true,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                setHasValidToken(true);
                console.log('valid token!');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.response.data.message) {
                    console.error(error.response.data.message);
                } else {
                    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
                }
                setHasValidToken(false);
                navigate('/login');
            });
    }, [navigate]);
```

Based on the result, it sets the state `hasValidToken`. Then return the following.

```js
return (
        <>
            {hasValidToken ? (
                <Route path={path} element={element} />
            ) : (
                <Navigate to="/login" />
            )}
        </>
    );
```

However, this ternary operator seems not working correctly.  What's more, it never console log the messages in the component. (I placed some `console.log` in the component)

I also tried to comment out everything inside `return` in the component, but still all protected route's path got rendered.

It's weird that all routes still can be rendered even though `ProtectedRoute` returns nothing.

I hope this makes sense and get help to figure out what's going on and what I might miss.

Comment: Custom route components are sort of anti-pattern now in `react-router-dom` v6, they don't work, and you don't really directly render `Route` components either, you should be seeing some console warnings from RRD regarding this. Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example for what you are trying to do, render, and how you are rendering?

Comment: What is the initial value of `hasValidToken` and what to do you want your component to render while the token is still being fetched?

Comment: @Bergi the initial value of `hasValidToken` is "undefined".